# Verificar se todos os campos de uma entidade é null

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma verificação de uma entidade `view model` no `C#` e tenho que validar se todos os campos são `null`, porque tenho que exigir pelo menos 1 filtro para continuar a rotina.

**Dúvida**: Qual melhor maneira mais simples e correta de se fazer isso?

**Obs**: Todos os campos são `nullables`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroOrd.Aprovada) 
|| !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtroOrd.Bloqueada) 
|| ...)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As respostas dadas já resolvem seu problema e são muito boas. Mas gostaria de contribuir com mais uma forma de fazer também usando `reflection`. A solução é a mesma no final das contas, mas acho que fica mais simples e legível.

O método abaixo verifica todas propriedades de qualquer objeto e retorna `true` apenas se todas propriedade forem **não nulas**.

```
public static bool VerificarPropriedadesNaoNulas<T>(this T obj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties().All(a => a.GetValue(obj) != null);    
}
```

**Chamada do método:**

```
var filtroOrd = new Filtro();
bool propriedadeNaoNulas = filtroOrd.VerificarPropriedadesNaoNulas();
```

Um ponto importante ressaltar que não há nas outras respostas:

`Reflection` pode ser bem lento e deve ser usado com cuidado. Para esse caso em específico não vejo problema e não acho que você perceberá diferença considerável. No entanto, sua abordagem na pergunta verificando item a item no `if` seria sem dúvida mais rápida.

Por outro lado, uma grande vantagem nessa abordagem usando o `Reflection` é que, mesmo que você adicione novas propriedades a sua classe, não será necessário manutenção no método e você evitará erro na aplicação caso sua classe seja alterada.

Answer (score 6):

Bom, gostaria de começar falando que não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer isso, mas pode-se usar `Reflection`, segue abaixo:

```
bool TemAlgumaPropriedadeComValor(object myObject)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string value = (string)pi.GetValue(myObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adicionei no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/de9G86) para referencia

Answer (score 6):

Vamos criar um método de extensão para validar se nossa ViewModel possui alguma propriedade nula.

Para começar iremos criar uma classe base para que todas nossas ViewModels herdem dela, assim conseguimos distinguir nossas ViewModels de outras classes no projeto:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    // Adicione propriedades que sejam comuns para todas suas ViewModels, aqui é apenas um exemplo.
    public int Identificador { get; set; }
}
```

Em seguida iremos fazer com que nossas ViewModels específicas herdem de nossa classe abstrata `ViewModelBase`, abaixo um exemplo:

```
public class PessoaViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public int? QuantidadeFilhos { get; set; }
}
```

Em seguida iremos criar uma classe que irá conter apenas métodos de extensão e nela teremos nosso método que irá tratar se nossa ViewModel possui algum campo nulo:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Projeto.Utilitario
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool ViewModelPossuiAlgumaPropriedadeNulaOuVazia<T>(this T obj) where T : ViewModelBase
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string value = Convert.ToString(propriedade.GetValue(obj));

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Para utilizar nosso método de extensão basta adicionarmos o namespace da classe `Extensions` e chamar o método:

```
using Projeto.Utilitario;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel
     {
         Nome = "Pedro",
         Sexo = "Masculino",
         DataNascimento = DateTime.Now
     };

    if (pessoaViewModel.ViewModelPossuiAlgumaPropriedadeNulaOuVazia())
    {
        // Implemente sua lógica caso possua algo vazio...
    }
}
```